# How to disable click handler on body on focus out(mobile)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable click handler on other elements on focus out of text fields. It works fine on desktop browsers but I am not able to restrict click on rest of body on mobile.

```
$(".text-box").on("focusout", function(event) {

});

$(".any-other-element").click(function(){

})
```

I want that click event attached on any-other-element should not fire on focus out of textbox.